SQL Server Replication - only ran once. How to configure scheduler from beginning
I have configured a transactional replication from server A to Server B some 2 month ago.
The source database is a new production server, and the data is being updated there constantly.
I have some issues ... I am not sure how to resolve.

I see that the "last sync" occurred 2 month ago, when I initially set it up.

I was expecting a snapshot job to be of a periodic nature, but it is not.
It is actually set to a "One time" and is not enabled. I know, I can "enable it" and
set the schedule for the future, however I am looking for how to do it at the time when I configure the replication.  I may be configuring it with the script and be expecing the configuration go into effect from the power shell script rn, and want to make sure i know how to set the schedule from the beginning.



This is what I see in a schedule of a Snapshot job on the Sql Server agent.


This is transactional or snapshot replication? There is a difference between those two

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@rois,
It is Transactional replication, as I mentioned in the beginning

@Community (bot)
"I know, I can "enable it" (Snapshot agent job) and set the schedule for the future, however I am looking for how to do it at the time when I (first)configure the replication. "

I think there is a misunderstanding how transactional replication works.
From documentation:

Transactional replication typically starts with a snapshot of the
publication database objects and data. As soon as the initial snapshot
is taken, subsequent data changes and schema modifications made at the
Publisher are usually delivered to the Subscriber as they occur (in
near real time).

So basically an initial snapshot is created and afterwards transaction log is scanned for any subsequent changes. Unless something breaks horribly or there is a need to add another subscriber ( and the initial snapshot expired), there is no need for additional snapshots. But even if that is the case, there is no need to fiddle with the agent job directly. I always did things similar to described in tutorial
It may be there is actually another problem as hinted by comment under the question. In this case new question would be appropiate in my opinion.

Thank you.  This is precisely how I understand Transactional Replication, and I was expecting the live (source) database to be CONSTANTLY replicated to the destination.  However, this does not happen.
The reason, I fiddled with the agent job, is because when at the time of a question I manually changed the schedule of the log reader job for experimenting, it picked up and now it is working.  Question, is:  Why did it only worked once from the get-go ?  And whether I could have missed anything in configuration ?
